# Distance $E_F-E_i$ in a compensated semiconductor

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, temperature, semiconductor-physics, electronics

Given two energy level diagrams for a compensated conductor:

At $0~\text{K}$

[image: Zero Kelvin]

At $500~\text{K}$

[image: 500K]

I want to determine for which diagram is the Fermi level closest/farthest from $E_i$. It's a compensated semiconductor so it behaves almost intrinsically. And since $E_F-E_i=kT\ln(n/n_i)$ it means that when $T=0$ we get $E_F=E_i$ and when $T>0$ then $E_F \neq E_i$. In other words at $T=0$ the Fermi level is closest from $E_i$ and at $T=500$ it's the farthest. However according to the [answers](http://www.ece.utep.edu/courses/ee3329/ee3329/Studyguide/Problems/Comp/index.html) it's the other way around. Why is that?